# batch loading UML elements to a class diagram in Papyrus

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, uml, papyrus

I went through the pain of generating a `.uml` model from java source in Eclipse.

I am using Papyrus for drawing diagrams, but it seems that the only way of displaying my model is manually dragging elements. Every `class/method/field/association` needs to be manually moved over.

This is quite a tedious task. I would think that a 'batch loading' of elements would be available, so is it? If there isn't, do you know of a tool that is able to use the same `.uml` format and has this functionality?

I'd rather move everything and weed out unneccesary stuff rather than spend hours DNDing.

Thanks!

Comment: Even if you do D&D all elements you still need to layout them in the diagram. And since one of the important aspects of visual diagrams is how "nice" they look, automatic layout is almost always not good.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been five years, but the current version of Papyrus does allow for drag and drop of many elements on a diagram, and you can multi-select to and bring up a context menu for commands to display information about the internal structure of the classes (for example).

Since the Neon release, Papyrus also has a much improved and tailorable layout mechanism that may meet your needs.

However, a ".uml" file typically does not contain any information with regards to diagrams, so there would be nothing to build on for diagram except for the layout tools.